Riemann-Stieltjes integral over a degenerate interval.
On the Wikipedia article of Riemann-Stieltjes integration they require that $a<b$ if we integrate over the interval $[a,b]$. However, in Rudin's "Principles of mathematical" analysis they do not require this.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral
https://www.amazon.com/Principles-Mathematical-Analysis-International-Mathematics/dp/007054235X
From what I see the integral $\int_a^a f dF(x)$ is always zero when viewed as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral?
So is this statement true?

Assume you have a random variable X. Define F(x) to be $P(X\le x)$,
this function is bounded, monotone, non-deacreasing and right-countinuous and $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} =0$. Define $\mu$ to be the
Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure of the distribution function $F$. Assume that $P(X=c)>0$.
Let $\int_c^c 1\cdot dF(x)$ be the Riemann-Stieltjes integral. We then have
$$\int_c^c 1\cdot dF(x)=0\ne P(X=c)=\int_{[c,c]}1\cdot d\mu.$$


The right hand side is the measure $\mu { c } = F(c) - F(c^-)$ so the two are equal (in which case, both are 0) if and only if $c$ is a continuity point of $F$. Does this answer your question?

@LNT Yes, thank you very much!

Glad that I can help :)

When you integrate through a point with positive measure, its contribution to the integral is the measure of that particular point, which equals the jump of the distribution function $F$. Riemann-Stieltjes integrals contain a "continuous" part where you integrate the density (in $L^1$) and a "discrete" part, corresponding to points where the density is a sum of delta functions. The latter gives you the sum of probabilities of points with positive probability ("atoms", as they say in measure theory).

Thank you, yes, I agree with your statement. But I am not after the sum of the probabilies of the atoms, I am after the probability of a single atom.

If your distribution is such that some particular values have positive probability, you have an atom. The integral over this atom = Its measure = its probability, and it is equal to the jump of F. That happens when you have a distribution which is a mix of continuous and discrete.

Riemann-Stieltjes and Lebesgue-Sieltjes are the same if the integrand is continuous. In this case the integrand is just $f=1$.

I agree with what you are saying, but does this mean that the answers to my questions are "yes" or "no"?
